# how to tune WebRtc Aec, echo cancelation?

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, aec

I added webrtc aec to my project, agc, ns too..

but VoIP quality is not good,

echo is not removed completely and howling.

is there any project to refer how to do tuning?

or is there any way to tune??

(i don't know how to set msSndCardBuf value in WebRtcAec_Process exactly)

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetUserMedia specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/#dom-mediatracksupportedconstraints) introduces the parameter `echoCancellation` as a `MediaTrackSupportedConstraints`

You can try it out and share if it works for you.